# How to handle errors in defer statements

Tags: go

So I have this:

```
defer res.Body.Close()
```

the problem is that this call can potentially return a non-nil error. So I assume the only way to properly capture the error is with this

```
defer func(){
  if err := defer res.Body.Close(); err !=nil {
     log.Error(err);
  }
}()
```

is there another way?

Comment: No. If you must handle the error, you must wrap it in another function. Return values are discarded when a function is called with `go` or `defer`. However, the question must be asked: does your application actually care if `res.Body.Close()` returns an error? Also your code is invalid, you cannot `if err := defer res.Body.Close()`, you must remove the `defer` there.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can't really make this statement
`err: = defer res.Body.Close ()` Like this. Therefore this statement is invalid.
The following is a valid one.

```
defer func(){
  if err := res.Body.Close(); err !=nil {
     log.Error(err);
  }
}()
```

Further, there is another way to handle errors in defer statements as follows.

```
func do() error {
  res, err := http.Get("http://notexists")
  if res != nil {
    defer res.Body.Close()
  }
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  // ..code...
  return nil
}
```

With the above code, when there’s an error, the code will return the error, otherwise, it’ll close res.Body when the func returns in defer.

You can visit https://blog.learngoprogramming.com/5-gotchas-of-defer-in-go-golang-part-iii-36a1ab3d6ef1 for more information on this.

Comment: but here again the potential error of `defer res.Body.Close()` isn't handled, or am I wrong?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You want to essentially "return" an error from the deferred code. Check out my answer for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As this isn't answered yet, here's a short solution.

You can use Golang's "named return values" in combination with `errors.Join` to append the error thrown in the `defer` function. The following is an example of my codebase where I revert the database transaction by deferring it. Note that the `tx.Rollback()` can return an `error`:

```golang
func (db *Database) ChangePost(id int, title string, excerpt string, content string) (err error) {
    tx, err := db.Connection.Begin()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer func() {
        err = errors.Join(tx.Rollback())
    }()
    ...
}
```

That way, the error from `tx.Rollback` isn't ignored and it passes linters such as `errcheck`.